# Error in linking a file during compilation of LLVM

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am compiling LLVM and Clang from source but getting the following error when it tries to link lib/libclang-cpp.so.14git:-

/usr/bin/ld.gold: internal error in open, at ../../gold/descriptors.cc:99

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I am using Gold Linker and my GCC version is 9.3.0. The LLVM branch is that of LLVM-12 (llvmorg-12.0.0). Earlier I was using LLD linker but that was causing memory overflow, after switching to Gold memory does not overflow but it still fails.

System specs:-

16GB RAM

512GB NVMe SSD

i7 10th Gen 8-cores

Also my swap size is 4GB. I have tried using lesser cores too, but the error still persists.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

P.S:- I am an absolute noob when it comes to LLVM.**strong text**

Comment: How many threads are you using to build LLVM? the link stage consumes much memory (maybe 8 GB for static linkage on debug build.)

Comment: I also encounter Memory overflow when compiling, then I switch to lld and succeed. Maybe you can try it: [lld](https://lld.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured this out. I was getting the same error, but building a different project.

Turns out that `gold` is bad at reporting errors. The actual issue is that the OS is running out of file descriptors. In my case it was set to `1024` (you can check with `ulimit -n`) but a large linking job needed more than that.

If you bump the number of file descriptors then `gold` works just fine.

```bash
# I choose 65536, you can change this number
ulimit -n 65536
```

Why do I say `gold` is bad at reporting errors? Because if you force it to run on multithreaded mode (it defaults to single threaded) then it properly reports:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: out of file descriptors and couldn't close any
```

Which is a more useful message.

Comment: This answer seems to work for me, after fixing a minor typo -- ulimit instead of uname.

Comment: This is the correct answer, it helped me compile LLVM 15

Comment: That worked a treat! Hopefully `gold` improves that error message before the next time that catches me :)